# My program isn't executing sums using different operators properly (when multiplying it adds and vice-versa)!

Tags: python, task, variable-assignment

I am trying to produce a program where the program generates a quiz consisting of a series of random questions, using in each case any two numbers and addition, subtraction or multiplication. The system should ask the student’s
name, then ask 10 questions, output if the answer to each question is correct or not and produce a final score out of 10.

The code goes as follows:

```
#Material 2: Task 1 (V1.0)

from random import randint
from random import choice

Name = input('What is your name? ')
Score = 0
QuestionNo = 0
Operators = ['+','-','*']
num1 = 0
num2 = 0


print ('\nWhat are the answers to the following questions?\n')

while QuestionNo != 11:
    num1 = randint(0,10)
    num2 = randint(0,10)
    Result = eval(str(num1) + (choice(Operators)) + str(num2))
    print (Result)
    Answer = int(input(str(num1) + (choice(Operators)) + str(num2) + '='))
    if Answer == Result:
        Score += 1
        print ('Well Done! That is correct!')
    elif Answer != Result:
        print ('Whoops! That is wrong!')
    QuestionNo += 1

    if QuestionNo == 10:
        print ('That is the end of the quiz '+ Name + '. Your score was: ' + str(Score) + ' out of 10!')
        if Score == 10:
            print ('Great job! You got everything right!')
        elif Score == 0:
            print ('You\'ve got to try harder next time!')
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the lines -

```
Result = eval(str(num1) + (choice(Operators)) + str(num2))
print (Result)
Answer = int(input(str(num1) + (choice(Operators)) + str(num2) + '='))
```

As you can see, you are taking `choice(Operators)` again, when asking for input from user, this can give different operator that what was used for calculating the result. You would need to take `choice(Operators)` only once, and save it in a variable and use it for both evaluation as well as input.

```
while QuestionNo != 11:
    num1 = randint(0,10)
    num2 = randint(0,10)
    opp = choice(Operators)
    Result = eval(str(num1) + (opp) + str(num2))
    print (Result)
    Answer = int(input(str(num1) + (opp) + str(num2) + '='))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved the poblem right away! Much appreciated.